# 'dummy' may be used uninitialized

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, clion

I have an issue running a clion project stepik file. The following error keeps showing up. I have a compiler and I can run other codes, but some doesn't work.

```
In file included from /home/gergoszabo/CLionProjects/Prog2_08/test-framework/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:42:
/home/gergoszabo/CLionProjects/Prog2_08/test-framework/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-death-test.cc: In function ‘bool testing::internal::StackGrowsDown()’:
/home/gergoszabo/CLionProjects/Prog2_08/test-framework/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-death-test.cc:1224:24: error: ‘dummy’ may be used uninitialized [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
 1224 |   StackLowerThanAddress(&dummy, &result);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/gergoszabo/CLionProjects/Prog2_08/test-framework/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-death-test.cc:1214:13: note: by argument 1 of type ‘const void*’ to ‘void testing::internal::StackLowerThanAddress(const void*, bool*)’ declared here
 1214 | static void StackLowerThanAddress(const void* ptr, bool* result) {
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/gergoszabo/CLionProjects/Prog2_08/test-framework/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-death-test.cc:1222:7: note: ‘dummy’ declared here
 1222 |   int dummy;
      |       ^~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
gmake[3]: *** [../test-framework/googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/build.make:72: ../test-framework/googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:587: ../test-framework/googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1394: lesson1/labbeli/CMakeFiles/global-lesson1-labbeli-test.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:598: global-lesson1-labbeli-test] Error 2
```

Comment: So, what is the actual question? You have a variable named `dummy` that is uninitialized when its address is passed to `StackLowerThanAddress()`. The compiler doesn't know what `StackLowerThanAddress()` will do with `dummy`, so it is simply **warning** you about a *potential* problem, if `StackLowerThanAddress()` were to try to read the value of `dummy`. But, you have the compiler set to treat all *warnings* as *errors*, even though this is probably not a fatal condition. If you don't want the warning to happen, then either initialize `dummy`, or use a compiler `#pragma` to disable the warning

Comment: It's like a test file which I have no access to, but it works on other computers, must be a problem with my IDE.

Comment: This doesn't appear to happen when the parameter is `void*`. It's possible the compiler is being smart and realizing that the parameter can't be changed without some dishonest shenanigans and therefore is probably read from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "The compiler doesn't know what `StackLowerThanAddress()` will do with `dummy`, so it is simply warning you about a potential problem" - No, the compiler won't emit such warning about a variable which usage is unknown. So the compiler actually **knows** that `StackLowerThanAddress` reads value of `dummy` (by pointer) before writing it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "*So the compiler actually **knows** that `StackLowerThanAddress` reads value of dummy*" - the only way it could know that for sure is if `StackLowerThanAddress` were an inline function. Otherwise it **can't** know for sure, hence why a *warning* is emitted. Think what happens if the implementation of `StackLowerThanAddress` were further down in the source file, or even in another translation unit.  Its behavior is not known at the call site. When the compiler sees a non-inline function call, it can't predict what that call will actually do at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Actually, no magic is here: As you can see from the error message, it references to the **definition** of function `StackLowerThanAddress` (note '{' after the signature). Also the function is **static**, so its body is definitely accessible in the translation unit which calls it.

Comment: Pull request which seems to fix the problem: https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/3024

Comment: @Tsyvarev, "No, the compiler won't emit such warning about a variable which usage is unknown." - That is incorrect: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f4Yhr8P4T. Note in particular that the warning uses the language *may*, as in might, indicating that it needn't be sure before issuing this warning.

Comment: @chris: Well, it seems the real behavior is somehow more complex. According to tests, the compiler emits the warning in two separate cases: 1. The compiler does **not sees the definition** of the called function **and** the type of parameter is **exactly** `const void*` (neither `void*` nor `const int*` emit a warning). 2. The compiler **sees the definition** of the called function **and** that definition dereferences the argument. In the given question it is definitely the second case, because the warning message points to the definition of the function.

Answer (score 8):

This problem is not in your own project, but in a library it seems to be using: GoogleTest.

The version of GoogleTest you're using currently has a problem when compiled with GCC 11. GCC gives off this warning (for various complex reasons). GoogleTest has configured that any warnings the compiler gives should be treated as errors. And so GCC will stop compiling when it encounters that warning.

It's not your mistake, but up to GoogleTest to fix. A fix has been made and merged here: https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/3024

Updating GoogleTest to use version 1.11.0 or newer should resolve the problem.

Comment: Pardon sir, [this project](https://github.com/JLospinoso/ccc) also uses GoogleTest to learn cpp also uses GoogleTest. Do you have a wild idea if the files inside this project will be affected by the last fix?